# Issues matching GoCardless Webhooks signature

Tags: python-3.x, base64, hmac, hashlib, gocardless

I am trying to match the Webhook signature received from GoCardless and am having difficulties.

Unfortunately there is no Error message to work with, it is simply that the signature I receive doesn't match any of the hash digests that I generate.

If someone could take a quick look at their docs, https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#webhooks-signing-webhooks, and let me know if I am missing something obvious that would be appreciated.

I am using Flask, hmac, hashlib and base64 modules.

```
# webhook signature
request.headers.get('Webhook-Signature').encode('utf-8')

# digest generated using the request body and SECRET key
digest = hmac.new(key = SECRET, msg=request.get_data(), digestmod = hashlib.sha256).digest()
base64.b64encode(digest)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So the issue is that    base64.b64encode(digest) does not equal   request.headers.get('Webhook-Signature').encode('utf-8')

Comment: [edit] your question instead of commenting